# Problema de autenticação com o firebase 3.0 em node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Em virtude do firebase ter atualizado para a versão 3.0 e ser necessário migrar para a nova versão, surgiu um problema quanto a autenticação do meu servidor node. O código tá tipo assim

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "<minha apiKey>",
  authDomain: "<meu domínio de autenticação>",
  databaseURL: "<url do banco>",
  storageBucket: "<minha storageBucket>",
  serviceAccount: "<nome do arquivo gerado pela conta de serviço>.json"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Ao rodar npm start, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials are invalid. 
This   usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. 
Make sure your apiKey and databaseURL match the values provided for your 
app at 'https://console.firebase.google.com/', or if you're using 
a service account, make sure it's authorized to access the specified 
databaseURL and is from the correct project.
```

Sendo que eu peguei todas as informações do config no meu próprio console do projeto no firebase.

Comment: O teu setup parece correto segundo [a API](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered). Tens a certeza que essas chaves estão corretas?

Comment: Sim, peguei do meu projeto no console, mas gostaria de saber se já aconteceu isso com alguém, pois suspeito que seja algum bug

Comment: @alissonoliveira isso aconteceu comigo, tira *todos* os outros items menos o `serviceAccount` e a `databaseURL`